# SQL Server if Statement >=

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

These are the questions:

Write a script that will give you six columns of output.

a)  the customer first name
b)  the customer last name
c)  the order number
d)  the item name
e)  the discount
f)  a column with the following words for the discount----either NONE, LESS THAN TWENTY, LESS THAN FORTY, or MORE THAN FORTY

I have done this:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.FirstName,
    Customers.LastName,
    Orders.OrderID,
    Products.ProductName,
    OrderItems.DiscountAmount,
    IF(OrderItems.DiscountAmount = 0, 'NONE', IF(OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 20, 'LESS THAN TWENTY', IF(OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 40, 'LESS THAN FORTY', 'MORE THAN FORTY'))) AS discount
FROM 
    Customers
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON (Customers.ShippingAddressID = Orders.ShipAddressID 
           AND Customers.BillingAddressID = Orders.BillingAddressID)
INNER JOIN 
    OrderItems ON (Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID)
INNER JOIN 
    Products ON (OrderItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
```

It gives me an error on my if statement? Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

This is the database I'm using:

[image]

Error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: No no no @JohnConde, actually understanding what's happening takes away all the fun!

Comment: The error message (and screenshot) suggest you are using MS SQL Server, not MySQL. I've retagged accordingly.

Comment: If this is truly an MSSQL question [you totally did not read the syntax of the IF command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: that's for the IF statement, not the expression, which is what the OP is trying to use here.

Comment: @siride to my knowledge MSSQL has no `IF` expression but an `IIF` expression.

Comment: adding IIF instead of IF on all IF fixes the problem. Or the CASE statement. Thanks

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: 2012 and later have `IIF`. Regardless of whether MSSQL has it or not, the OP was clearly trying to implement the expression.

Comment: @siride that wasn't my point, I was pointing out that he didn't read the manual for 5 seconds before spending much MUCH longer on typing a question here.

Answer (score 4):

Your database diagram and errors suggest you are using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. The `IF` command/expression/keyword is not standardized and implemented differently in different platforms.

Therefore you should not use [MySQL proprietary `IF`-syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) but the [MSSQL proprietary `IIF`-syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx). `IF` is a [control-of-flow statement in MSSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use "case..when" statement here. Usage link here: [case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
Case 
    when OrderItems.DiscountAmount = 0 then 'NONE' 
    when OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 20 then 'LESS THAN TWENTY' 
    when OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 40 then 'LESS THAN FORTY' 
    else 'MORE THAN FORTY' 
End AS discount
```

Comment: If you down vote, please add a comment to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL Server.  There is no `if` statement.  Use `case`:

```
(CASE WHEN OrderItems.DiscountAmount = 0 THEN 'NONE'
      WHEN OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 20 THEN 'LESS THAN TWENTY'
      WHEN OrderItems.DiscountAmount <= 40 THEN 'LESS THAN FORTY'
      ELSE 'MORE THAN FORTY'
 END) AS discount
```

Comment: Parentheses are fine.